# Requested JSON parse failed en Login

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, json

Tengo un problema que no he podido solucionar.

Esto en mi equipo personal (localhost) funciona sin problemas, pero cuando subí el sistema a mi hosting, no funciona el logueo.
El error que me da es

> Requested JSON parse failed.

Tengo lo siguiente:

Mi formulario:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-material" id="Frm" action="">

      <div class="form-group m-t-40">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="form-control" name="t_user" type="text" required="" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus autocomplete="off">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="form-control" name="t_pass" type="password" required="" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group text-center m-t-20">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <input class="btn btn-info btn-block botonlg" type="submit" value="Ingrese"/>
        </div>
      </div>
</form>

<script src="plugins/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

En el archivo `main.js` tengo lo siguiente:

```
    jQuery(document).on('submit','#Frm',function(event){
    "use strict";
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'loginexe.php',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.botonlg').val('Validando...');
        }
    })

    .done(function(respuesta){
        console.log("respuesta");
        if (!respuesta.error){
            if(respuesta.tipo === 'gim'){
                location.href = 'gim/';
            }
        }else{
            $('.error').slideDown('slow');
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.error').slideUp('slow');
            },3000);
            $('#Frm')[0].reset();
            $('.botonlg').val('Ingrese'); 
        }
    })

    .fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            alert('Requested page not found [404]');

          } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

            alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

          } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

            alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

            alert('Time out error.');

          } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

            alert('Ajax request aborted.');

          } else {

            alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

          }
    })
    .always(function(){
        console.log("complete");
    });
});
```

Y en mi archivo `loginexe.php`

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){

require 'config.php';
session_start();

$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');

$usuario = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['t_user']);
$pas = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['t_pass']);

if ($nueva_consulta = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, nombre, tipo FROM clientes WHERE user = ? AND pass = ? ")){

    $nueva_consulta->bind_param('ss', $usuario, $pas);
    $nueva_consulta->execute();
    $resultado = $nueva_consulta->get_result();
    if($resultado->num_rows == 1){
            $datos = $resultado->fetch_assoc();
            $_SESSION['usuario'] = $datos;
            echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'tipo' => $datos['tipo']));
    }else{
            echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }
    $nueva_consulta->close();
}

}

 $mysqli->close();
```

Tanto la conexión a la base de datos y los datos de la tabla cliente, son correctos.

Actualmente, para acceder al sistema, lo hago a través de un subdominio. Pensé que ese era el problema, pero lo agregue como una carpeta interna del dominio y el problema persiste.

Si alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionarlo, agradezco me oriente para aplicar una posible solución.

Como siempre, agradecido por su ayuda.
Saludos a todos.

Comment: Pero ya viste que te respondió el server ? por lo que veo tu controlas los mensajes  , o revisar el archivo log de tu hosting normalmente se crea en la ruta donde se encuentra tu archivo php login.php exe , cuando se generan errores y otra sugerencia revisar lo que dice la consola de tu navegador ahí puedes encontrar mas detalles

Comment: Me pasa exactamente lo mismo. Alguna sugerencia?